# How do I guess (best searching algorithm) any positive integer from a system which can only reply in a Yes or a No?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search, linear-search

Let us say the system only gives yes or no if you guess the right number.
Lets take two examples where

**1. number = 3**

**2. number = 134567894567**

As you can see the first number can be found if you made linear call like:-

```
is the number = 1? No
is the number = 2? No
is the number = 3? Yes
```

So a **linear** search algorithm would be easier to implement.

However if the element is as large as **134567894567** maybe going the **binary search** way would make sense. how do I build a system which provides best results keeping the above constraints in mind.

Comment: Binary search only works with sorted data. If you were able to get the input to have a minimum and a maximum value that constrained the numbers available to choose, you could create an array of numbers between the minimum and maximum values that is sorted that could then be used for binary search.

Comment: @klaurtar1 you don't need an array to use binary search.  The only restriction is that you must have a minimum and maximum value.

Comment: Also function on which your'e searching must be monotonic, in this case when system only replies `Yes` and `No` binary search cannot be applied, if instead System replied if number we are searching for is `<=query`, `>=query` then we could use binary search

Comment: @klaurtar1 I agree. As you can see there is no array or list involved. You do not have a list of numbers , Just a random number. Binary search is used as a way of guessing the element.

Comment: @Photon so what alternative do you suggest I have in such case? Linear should not be the absolute answer.

Comment: @Jagvir well we can't do anything better than linear unless we have more information about the system

Comment: Binary search works if each test answers "higher" or "lower".  If each test just answers "yes" or "no", then it doesn't matter what order you test numbers in.  No matter what order you choose, then answer may be the last one you check.

Comment: does the system tell you yes/no on your guess if its higher/lower than the number?

Comment: @MattTimmermans you can get Yes/No to work if you just change the question.  Instead of asking `Is the number = 3?`, ask `Is the number < 3?`.

Comment: @MarkRansom  I think that's what I said :)

Comment: @MattTimmermans that wasn't clear to me at all.  What I got from your statement is that it's impossible to do a binary search based on yes/no answers.  You didn't mention changing the *questions* at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use binary search if the system will give you a yes/no answer.
You need to use linear search.

In order to use binary search, the conditions are:

1. The range must be bounded.
2. At each 'guess', it must tell you the direction you need to head towards.

That's the minimal requirement to use binary search.
So for your current situation, where you are not getting the required information, you must use linear search as you originally proposed.